# DES Crypto applet returns errror on reception of any command

Tags: java, cryptography, javacard

In the below you see a simple Java Card applet that is written to encrypt and decrypt data with different `DES` and `3DES` algorithms.

**These are supported commands :**

1. **`00 C0 00 00 | KeyLength | KeyValue`**  : To set the DES/3DES Key. (8 byte for DES, 16/24 bytes for 2Key/3Key 3DES algorithm)
2. **`00 C1 XX YY | DataLength | DataValue`** : For DES Encryption/Decryption
3. **`00 C2 XX YY | DataLength | DataValue`** : For 2Key 3DES Encryption/Decryption
4. **`00 C3 XX YY | DataLength | DataValue`** : For 3Key 3DES Encryption/Decryption

> `XX = 0x00` : DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1
>
> `XX = 0x01` : DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2
>
> `XX = 0x02` : DES_CBC_NOPAD
>
> `XX = 0x03` : DES_CBC_PKCS5
>
> `XX = 0x04` : DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1
>
> `XX = 0x05` : DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2
>
> `XX = 0x06` : DES_ECB_NOPAD
>
> `XX = 0x07` : DES_ECB_PKCS5
>
> `YY = 0x00` : Encrypt
>
> `YY = 0x01` : Decrypt

**The program :**

```
package cryptoPack;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.JCSystem;
import javacard.framework.Util;
import javacard.security.DESKey;
import javacard.security.KeyBuilder;
import javacardx.crypto.Cipher;

public class CryptoDES extends Applet {

    // Array for the encryption/decryption key
    private byte[] TheDES_Key = { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00 };

    // Defining required Keys
    DESKey MyDES1Key = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,
            KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES, false);
    DESKey MyDES2Key = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,
            KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES3_2KEY, false);
    DESKey MyDES3Key = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,
            KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES3_3KEY, false);

    // Defining required cipher
    Cipher MyCipher;

    // Defining switch case variables for supported instructions
    final byte SetKey = (byte) 0xC0;
    final byte OneKeyDES = (byte) 0xC1;
    final byte TwoKeyDES = (byte) 0xC2;
    final byte ThreeKeyDES = (byte) 0xC3;

    // Defining switch case variables for cipher algorithms
    final byte DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1 = (byte) 0x00;
    final byte DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2 = (byte) 0x01;
    final byte DES_CBC_NOPAD = (byte) 0x02;
    final byte DES_CBC_PKCS5 = (byte) 0x03;
    final byte DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1 = (byte) 0x04;
    final byte DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2 = (byte) 0x05;
    final byte DES_ECB_NOPAD = (byte) 0x06;
    final byte DES_ECB_PKCS5 = (byte) 0x07;

    // Defining Proprietary Status Words
    final short KeyInNotSetGood = 0x6440;

    // A flag to be sure that the configured key has the same length that the
    // algorithm needs.
    byte ConfiguredKeyLength = 0;

    private CryptoDES() {

    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new CryptoDES().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {

        // Assigning 0 to "ConfiguredKeyLength" to force the user to use ...
        // ... "SetKey" command, after applet selection.
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            ConfiguredKeyLength = 0;
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        // Checking the CLA field in the APDU command.
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != 0) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

        // Checking the P1 and P2 fields in the APDU command.
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] > 7 || buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] > 1) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INCORRECT_P1P2);
        }

        // Analyzing the command.
        try {

            switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {

            case SetKey:
                SetCryptoKeyAndInitCipher(apdu);
                break;

            case OneKeyDES:
                OneKeyDESCrypto(apdu);
                DoEncryptDecrypt(apdu);
                break;

            case TwoKeyDES:
                TwoKeyDESCrypto(apdu);
                DoEncryptDecrypt(apdu);
                break;

            case (byte) ThreeKeyDES:
                ThreeKeyDESCrypto(apdu);
                DoEncryptDecrypt(apdu);
                break;

            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof CryptoException) {
                ISOException.throwIt(((CryptoException) e).getReason());
            }
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_UNKNOWN);

        }

    }

    public void SetCryptoKeyAndInitCipher(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Key must has a length of 8, 16 or 24 bytes
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] == 8 || buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] == 16
                || buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] == 24) {
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, TheDES_Key,
                    (short) 0, ISO7816.OFFSET_LC);

            ConfiguredKeyLength = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC];

        } else {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_DATA_INVALID);
        }

        switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1]) {
        case DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1:
            MyCipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1, false);
            break;
        case DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2:
            MyCipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2, false);
            break;
        case DES_CBC_NOPAD:
            MyCipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, false);
            break;
        case DES_CBC_PKCS5:
            MyCipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_PKCS5, false);
            break;
        case DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1:
            MyCipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1, false);
            break;
        case DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2:
            MyCipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2, false);
            break;
        case DES_ECB_NOPAD:
            MyCipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_NOPAD, false);
            break;
        case DES_ECB_PKCS5:
            MyCipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_PKCS5, false);
            break;

        }

    }

    public void OneKeyDESCrypto(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Check to see if the configured key is the required key for this ...
        // ... algorithm or not
        if (ConfiguredKeyLength != 8) {
            ISOException.throwIt(KeyInNotSetGood);
        }
        MyDES1Key.setKey(TheDES_Key, (short) 0);

        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == 1) {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES1Key, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        } else {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES1Key, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);

        }

    }

    public void TwoKeyDESCrypto(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Check to see if the configured key is the required key for this ...
        // ... algorithm or not

        if (ConfiguredKeyLength != 16) {
            ISOException.throwIt(KeyInNotSetGood);
        }
        MyDES2Key.setKey(TheDES_Key, (short) 0);

        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == 1) {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES2Key, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        } else {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES2Key, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);

        }

    }

    public void ThreeKeyDESCrypto(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Check to see if the configured key is the required key for this ...
        // ... algorithm or not
        if (ConfiguredKeyLength != 24) {
            ISOException.throwIt(KeyInNotSetGood);
        }

        MyDES3Key.setKey(TheDES_Key, (short) 0);

        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == 1) {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES3Key, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        } else {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES3Key, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);

        }

    }

    public void DoEncryptDecrypt(APDU apdu) {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        byte[] CipheredData = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 32,
                JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

        short datalen = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
        if ((datalen % 8) != 0) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_DATA_INVALID);
        }

        MyCipher.doFinal(buffer, (short) 0, datalen, CipheredData, (short) 0);
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(CipheredData, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0,
                datalen);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, datalen);
    }

}
```

**Run-time output:**

```
OSC: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00c10000081122334455667788 -s 00c20000081011121314151617

Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0

//Selecting the applet
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)

//Assign 1122334455667788 as the crypto key
Sending: 00 C1 00 00 08 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88
Received (SW1=0x6F, SW2=0x00)

//Request to "encrypt" "1011121314151617" with "DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1"
Sending: 00 C2 00 00 08 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
Received (SW1=0x6F, SW2=0x00)
```

**Questions :**

1. How a professional programmer write the above program to make it more efficient and more secure? (Any improvement : Scope of declaration and definition of variables, type of variables and so on)
2. Why the applet returns error on reception of any of its supported APDU commands?

**Update :**

2.1: My IDE (Eclipse), **warn** me *The static method `getInstance(byte,boolean)` from the type Cipher should be accessed in a static way* What does this mean? Why should I?

2.2: In the above program I supposed that the Length of my input data is less than 32 byte and is multiple of `8` bytes also. How to make the length variable? One solution is using `new` keyword, but I think this is the worst solution. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1**

StackOverflow is not meant to be a site for peer code reviews. Just a few obvious observations nevertheless:

- Follow the Java code conventions: `myCipher` instead of `MyCipher`, `KEY_IN_NOT_SET_GOOD` instead of `KeyInNotSetGood` etc. (see https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html). These rules can improve the readability of your code a lot.
- Never use static method in a non-static way (use `Cipher.getInstance(...)` instead of `myCipher.getInstance(...)`). (`static` marker - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)
- Surround the whole content of your `process` method with a try-catch block and handle all exceptions you catch. Then set the status word according to the type and the reason of your exception. Otherwise you get only `6F00`, which carries almost no information.
- `ConfiguredKeyLength` must be stored in RAM. Your way would destroy the card very soon (each SELECT rewrites the EEPROM cell).

**Q2**

Firstly, there is one very common mistake:

```
Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, TheDES_Key,
                    (short) 0, ISO7816.OFFSET_LC);
```

instead of

```
 Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, TheDES_Key,
                    (short) 0, buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC]);
```

(was it you to whom I told it a week ago here at StackOverflow, btw?)

The second problem: you do not call

`apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();`

before touching the data part of your APDU buffer. This can cause a lot of troubles.

The third problem: you create the Cipher instance in an incorrect way. Write:

```
MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, false);
```

instead of

```
MyCipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, false);
```

That is why you get a `NullPointerException` - `MyCipher` always remains `null`.

Comment: Thank you dear vojta; may I ask you to add some detail for second problem? Why I must call `apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();` in this program?

Comment: And yes, I am the same person. I did that mistake again, and I promise I won't repeat it again. ;) If you let me, I keep the question open for 24 hours more and then accept your answer.

Comment: :-) . APDU is always in one of possible "states". If you do not call `apdu.setIncomingAndReceive()`, it stays in STATE_INITIAL, which means input data might not be available in the buffer (depending on the JavaCard implementation). See http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/framework/APDU.html

Comment: Congrats hitting 1K reputation ;)